# Encrypt and decrypt a google Firebase realtime database entry

Tags: android, firebase, encryption, firebase-realtime-database, public-key-encryption

I am making an app on android studio with a Firebase backed. 
It currently stores information about the user that they upload their selves in their own sections of the Firebase database. It is stored in the structure that uses their uuid of their Firebase account and puts all their uploads under that i.e. their pictures, reminders, notes and passwords.

I would like to encrypt the passwords section in the database so even I can not read it. When i say passwords section i mean the part in the app that allows users to store their own new generated passwords for other things ; not the password they use to login to the app, i know this is already encrypted and want to know how to achieve this myself.

How would i go about it? Would i need to use the users auth/uuid that you can get from Firebase after they login as a private key to encrypt the password or any other data as they are uploading it? And store the public key somewhere in their section of the Firebase database? I am not very experienced when it comes to encryption.

If someone could please give me some sort of direction on how i should go about encrypting this data so even i cant read it from the back end that would be great thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to store the users password for an authentication. If you intend to use Firebase authentication for your users, Firebase stores the passwords for you with their encryption algorithms.

Please visit ofiical [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth) for using Firebase authentication.

Hope it helps.

Comment: i have a part in my app that is meant to allow users to store different passwords for other real world things and create new randomly generated passwords then store those new passwords in their section of the fire base database, not their actual password they use to login i l know that is already encrypted and i want to encrypt their own uploaded passwords, not the one they use to login to my app. thank you

Comment: If your app has all the tools to encrypt and decrypt theses passwords, it means an attacker could do just the same if they gained access to your server.

Comment: @LucasKrupinski Hello, thank you for your reply. I see, so if the private key was stored locally on the device and the public key was stored in the database an attacker could easily use these to get to the information? but even so i dont really mind. The point is to just get the database so it is not easily readable to me or anyone else that can view the fire base database tables.

Comment: @JohnSmith if the device is sending you the password, which you then encrypt with their public key, an attacker could potentially grab that password before it's been encrypted. If the client has a private key already, why not use just have client encrypt that data before it even sends to you? Then your server /firebase only ever recieves encrypted data.

Comment: @LucasKrupinski Thank you i will have a look at encrypting the data client side to send encrypted data to firebase and then decrypt it client side

Comment: hi @JohnSmith, did you find the solution for is question? I too need the same requirement. Please suggest your idea with  me what you have done.